# maven module not build from parent module

Tags: java, maven

I have an issue with a maven project after integrating PMD.
 I have added a new module in the parent :

```
 <module>x-build-tools</module>
```

It is also used as a dependency in a plugin(in the same parent pom)

```
 <build>
 ...
 <plugin>
 ...
  <dependencies>
     <dependency>
         <groupId>com.x.x</groupId>
         <artifactId>x-build-tools</artifactId>
         <version>0.4-SNAPSHOT</version>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </plugin>
```

In the module pom I have this :

```
 <parent>
        <artifactId>x-ms</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.x.x</groupId>
        <version>0.4-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>x-build-tools</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.x.x</groupId>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <name>X Build Tools</name>
```

The problem is that if I build the parent project I will get an error saying that it can't find the module on the repository. However if I build the module first and then the parent project it will work.
 I have managed to get around this problem by removing the parent section from the module and it worked but I don't know how good this is.

Can someone explain what is happening ?

Thank you,
Marius

Comment: do you have a plugin repository defined in the modul pom.xml?

Comment: no, I don't have this defined in my module pom

Comment: You have a parent which has a module and a dependency to that same module, this is cyclic it will not work.

Comment: I have had another look at the documentation : https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-pmd-plugin/examples/multi-module-config.html and indeed they are missing the <parent> part from the module. How does this fixes the cyclic dependency ? It is still a module of the parent project ...